# Could not find play-services-maps.jar from maven repository - react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, google-play-services

I was trying to install react-native-google-maps and in got this message in compile time:

```
    > Could not find play-services-maps.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://maven.google.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/12.0.1/play-services-maps-12.0.1.jar
```

And the problem is the provided link is brook

Are there any reason that why google removed this link?

Comment: Do you use Proxy on your internet?

Answer (score 1):

Update play-services-maps version to 15.0.0 instead of current 12.0.1 in Android/App/build.gradle file.